# Windows 7 Home Prem

Tags: windows-7, boot, usb

In my laptop, I already have a Win7 original copy and the recovery partition in drive D. When I open D however, the system asks me to enter media in order to get my recovery. I entered USB flash with 32GB and the recovery moved to USB flash and the drive D formatted automatically.

**My problem:**

How can I restore the recovery using the USB. I tried many times to boot from USB with no success. even I change the bios to boot from UEFI. The USB contains two main folders and many hidden files. I believe I can't convert it to ISO. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First clone that drive you have somewhere, preferrably onto another USB drive the same size. Then you have to make one of your USB drives bootable, which will completely wipe it but will add an MBR(Master Boot Record), if you have not done that already.  Most of the time when you purchase a USB drive, it is factory formatted as a FDD, what you want is USB drive that is formatted as a HDD so here is a quick link to do just that, The bootsect.exe, should be in your backup directory that you just put on your drive.

http://www.computerhope.com/issues/ch001366.htm